# Win32 API LogonUser Offline Access to Local Account

Tags: c#, winapi

Is there some series of flags that will allow `LogonUser` to return a token useable for impersonation of a local user when the computer is NOT connected to a network (but all accounts already exist locally).

I have the domain account executing the app

> MYDOMAIN\FooUser

and I'm trying to get an impersonation token for

> MYLAPTOP\TestUser

Then I read a series of text files in a folder which all can be read by `FooUser`, but some have the read privilege denied for `TestUser`.

If I login to Windows and run the app from `TestUser` the privileges map correctly and permissions are denied on the files.  If I'm connected to my domain and run the app from `FooUser` I can also impersonate `TestUser` and the file permissions again properly deny access as expected (using `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE`).

The problem occurs when my Ethernet cable is unplugged and I try to call `LogonUser` for `TestUser` and I expected that I'd be able to somehow validate local credentials... locally?

Using `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE`:

- Entering credentials for `TestUser` returns error indicating "Bad username or password"
- Entering credentials for `FooUser` returns error indicating "No logon servers available" (makes sense, I'm not complaining... except how did I sign into Windows in the first place when not connected to my domain?)

Using `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS`:

- Entering  gibberish credentials returns a token that appears to have the same access as `FooUser`

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Common.NativeMethods.Enumerations;

namespace Common.NativeMethods
{
    public static class AdvApi32
    {
        // http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.logonuser
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.securestringtoglobalallocunicode(v=vs.100).aspx

        // PInvoke into the Win32 API to provide access to the  
        // LogonUser and CloseHandle functions.
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern bool LogonUser(
            IntPtr username,
            IntPtr domain,
            IntPtr password,
            LogonType logonType,
            LogonProvider logonProvider,
            ref IntPtr token
        );

        public static WindowsIdentity LogonUser(SecureString p_userName, SecureString p_password, SecureString p_domainName)
        {
            IntPtr UserAccountToken = IntPtr.Zero;

            IntPtr UserNamePointer = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr PasswordPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr DomainNamePointer = IntPtr.Zero;

            try
            {
                // Marshal the SecureString to unmanaged memory.
                UserNamePointer = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(p_password);
                PasswordPointer = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(p_userName);
                DomainNamePointer = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(p_domainName);

                // Call LogonUser, passing the unmanaged (and decrypted) copy of the SecureString password.
                bool ReturnValue =
                    AdvApi32
                        .LogonUser(
                            UserNamePointer,
                            DomainNamePointer,
                            PasswordPointer,
                            LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, //.LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS,
                            LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, //.LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50,
                            ref UserAccountToken);

                // Get the Last win32 Error and throw an exception. 
                if (!ReturnValue && UserAccountToken == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

                    throw
                        new Win32Exception(error);
                }

                // The token that is passed to the following constructor must  
                // be a primary token in order to use it for impersonation.
                return
                    new WindowsIdentity(UserAccountToken);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Zero-out and free the unmanaged string reference.
                Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(UserNamePointer);
                Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(PasswordPointer);
                Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(DomainNamePointer);

                // Close the token handle.
                Kernel32.CloseHandle(UserAccountToken);
            }
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Security;

namespace Common.NativeMethods
{
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

    public static class Kernel32
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that LogonUser fails when trying to get the user token for the local "TestUser" account, and that this is your problem?

Comment: Not quite. It works when I am connected to my corporate domain network, but not when I am offline. Note that this is a WinForms app.  I wondered if there was some way to access the cached credentials... since I can obviously log into `FooUser` or `TestUser` on my laptop without being connected to my corporate network.  I just can't find a way to `Impersonate` either user (but more importantly `TestUser`) when not connected.

Comment: When impersonating TestUser, how do you obtain TestUser's token? More specifically, what are the domain and user arguments when calling LogonUser? Have you tried "." as (local) domain name for TestUser?

Comment: Yes, of course that works when my laptop is connected to my corporate network. That is to say I have the ethernet cable plugged in while I'm at work.  But if I try to work on this stuff at my house, I can't use `LogonUser` to `Impersonate()` either user anymore because there is no domain server to handle my authentication request.  But I can still sign in to either account from the Windows login screen and get to the Windows Desktop, so clearly credentials are cached somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops... I made a typo when I was refactoring. `LogonUser` works just fine when not connected to the domain; if you point to the correct parameters at least.

```cs
 UserNamePointer = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(p_password);
 PasswordPointer = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(p_userName);
```

Fixed

```cs
 UserNamePointer = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(p_userName);
 PasswordPointer = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(p_password);
```